# Presheaf with same global sections as associated sheaf

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

My question is very easy to state : if a presheaf has the same global sections as its associated sheaf, is it a sheaf ?

I imagine its false but havent found a counter example.

Comment: No this is false in general. For example, take the constant presheaf with value $\mathbb{Z}$ on every open set. Its associated sheaf is the sheaf of locally constant function $U\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}$. Such a function is actually constant if $U$ is connected. Hence, the global sections of this presheaf coincide with the global sections of the associated sheaf (if your space is connected).

Comment: Ah yes thank you very much !

Comment: Note, that in the definition of a sheaf on $X$, we require the two sheaf axioms to hold for all open sets $U \subset X$ and coverings $\{U_i\}$ of $U$.

If your question was true, we only would need this to hold for $U=X$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the sheaf $ \mathcal C$ of continuous functions on $[0,1]$ and its  subpresheaf $\mathcal C_b\subset \mathcal C$ of bounded continuous functions .
The sheaf associated to $\mathcal C_b$ is $\mathcal C$ (because every continuous function is **locally** bounded) but we have  $\mathcal C_b\subsetneq \mathcal C$, since $\frac 1x\in \mathcal C(0,1)\setminus \mathcal C_b(0,1)$.
However the presheaf and the sheaf have the same global sections $\mathcal C_b[0,1]=\mathcal C[0,1]$, since a continuous function on the **compact** interval $[0,1]$ is necessarily bounded.

Comment: Nice thanks a lot :) (i can't upvote because I dont have a full account)

Comment: Don't worry, dear Tchichikov: I am quite happy that you accepted this answer so quickly :-)